# Gilden-Fire hardcover by Stephen Donaldson

Tags: books, stephen-r-donaldson

Does anyone know which is the true first edition? The US or the UK? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search about the publishing dates for the first editions of the [UK Version](https://www.google.com/search?q=when+was+gilden+fire+UK+first+edition+released%3F&oq=when+was+gilden+fire+UK+first+edition+released%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.11880j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the [US Version](https://www.google.com/search?q=when+was+gilden+fire+US+first+edition+released%3F&oq=when+was+gilden+fire+US+first+edition+released%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.11880j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals the US edition as the true first edition.

The date for the US Version was found by the Google Query - 'when was gilden fire US first edition released?' and the UK Version by - 'when was gilden fire UK first edition released?'

Comment: I tried searching for them as 'hardcover' as well, but the dates were no different from the general search.

Answer (score 1):

In any question about SF publications, your first stop should be the [Internet Science Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/).  It includes publication details, and much else, for the vast majority of published SF for the past century.

The [page for *Gilden-Fire*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1022094) lists the [first U.S. publication](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?235141), in a limited 1000-copy (plus 275 signed copies) hardcover printing by Underwood-Miller, dated as 1981-11-00 (November 1981).  Note that this listing is marked as "verified" which means that the listing details have been checked against a primary source, most likely either the publisher's records or a copy of the book.

The [first publication in the U.K.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15458), by contrast, is a hardcover release by Collins dated 1983-10-00, or October 1983.

Note that if you're looking for a true first edition, which may be difficult to find with only 1275 copies, you should not confuse it with the [Science Fiction Book Club (SFBC) edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?109581) (#2044) released later, which has the same cover art but a different background colour.  It was still released, in October 1982, before the U.K. edition, though.  (I know that buying older books secondhand online I've gotten burned a couple of times with SFBC editions.)